# return array of strings

Tags: solidity, arrays, returndata

how do I return an array of strings? This is my code:

```
contract PlanetEarthContract {
    string[7] continents;
    constructor() public {
        continents = ["North America", "South America", "Europe", 
        "Asia", "Oceania", "Antartica", "Africa"];}

        function getCountries() public view returns(string[7] memory){
        return(continents);
    }

}
```

But I get the error

> This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without the experimental ABI encoder. You can turn that on with, per https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/layout-of-source-files.html#abiencoderv2:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```